# How to convert MySQL Query to CodeIgniter Syntax?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, syntax

I am currently working on a MySQL query. When it already delivers the correct needed data, I figured out that it needed to be converted to CodeIgniter syntax for me to be able to use it in a custom model in GroceryCRUD. I tried manually inputting all the select, join and where values to every suited statement

```
(e.g. $this->db->select("tul1.u_Uname AS MSN, and so on...)
```

but it does not work. I also tried using

```
$this->db->query(and my query goes here)
```

my code runs fine but the GroceryCRUD would not display the fields. I tried running a simple query that follows the default syntax

```
(e.g $this->db->select("fgrade_Id, CONCAT_WS ( ' ', tbluserlist.u_LastName, tbluserlist.u_FirstName ) AS Student", false);
```

and was able to display the result but I wasn't successful in converting the actual query that I needed for the said task. The actual query that I am working on is:

```
SELECT tul1.u_Uname AS MSN, REPLACE(CONCAT_WS(' ',  CONCAT_WS('',tul1.u_LastName, ','),  IF (tul1.u_SuffixName = 'NONE' OR tul1.u_SuffixName LIKE '%n/a%' OR tul1.u_SuffixName LIKE '%n\\a%', CONCAT_WS('',tul1.u_FirstName, ','), tul1.u_FirstName), IF (tul1.u_SuffixName = 'NONE' OR tul1.u_SuffixName LIKE '%n/a%' OR tul1.u_SuffixName LIKE '%n\\a%', '',  CONCAT_WS('', tul1.u_SuffixName, ',')), IF (tul1.u_MiddleName = 'NONE' OR tul1.u_MiddleName LIKE '%n/a%' OR tul1.u_SuffixName LIKE '%n\\a%', '',  tul1.u_MiddleName)), '  ', ' ') AS Student, CONCAT_WS(' ',  sc.course_RefNo, '~',  sc.course_Title) AS Course, REPLACE(CONCAT_WS(' ',  CONCAT_WS('',tul2.u_LastName, ','),  IF (tul2.u_SuffixName = 'NONE' OR tul2.u_SuffixName LIKE '%n/a%' OR tul2.u_SuffixName LIKE '%n\\a%', CONCAT_WS('',tul2.u_FirstName, ','), tul2.u_FirstName), IF (tul2.u_SuffixName = 'NONE' OR tul2.u_SuffixName LIKE '%n/a%' OR tul2.u_SuffixName LIKE '%n\\a%', '',  CONCAT_WS('', tul2.u_SuffixName, ',')), IF (tul2.u_MiddleName = 'NONE' OR tul2.u_MiddleName LIKE '%n/a%' OR tul2.u_SuffixName LIKE '%n\\a%', '',  tul2.u_MiddleName)), '  ', ' ') AS Instructor, tfg.fgrade_Grade AS FinalGrade, tfl.fl_AY AS AY, tfl.fl_SemId AS SemId, ss.yrsem_Sem AS Semester, tfg.fgrade_DateEncoded, tfg.fgrade_Visible, tfg.fgrade_Id FROM egmsdbdev.tblfinalgrade AS tfg INNER JOIN egmsdbdev.tblfacultyloading AS tfl ON tfg.fgrade_FLId = tfl.fl_Id INNER JOIN egmsdbdev.tbluserlist AS tul1 ON tul1.u_SpId = tfg.fgrade_SpId INNER JOIN egmsdbdev.set_course AS sc ON tfl.fl_CourseId = sc.course_Id INNER JOIN egmsdbdev.tbluserlist AS tul2 ON tfl.fl_FacultyId = tul2.u_Id INNER JOIN dbris.set_yrsem AS ss ON tfl.fl_SemId = ss.yrsem_id LEFT JOIN egmsdbdev.tblfinalgrade tfg2 ON (tfg.fgrade_SpId = tfg2.fgrade_SpId AND tfg.fgrade_FLId = tfg2.fgrade_FLId AND tfg.fgrade_Id<tfg2.fgrade_Id ) WHERE tfl.fl_CourseId NOT IN ((SELECT nnc_CourseId from set_nonnumericcourse)) AND tfg2.fgrade_Id IS NULL ORDER BY Student, Course
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I am using GroceryCRUD and custom models would only run using Active Records that is why I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to convert it! Thank you for the suggestions.. :)

```
        $this->db->select('
        tul1.u_Uname AS MSN,
        REPLACE(CONCAT_WS(" ",  CONCAT_WS("",tul1.u_LastName, ","),  IF (tul1.u_SuffixName = "NONE" OR tul1.u_SuffixName LIKE "%n/a%" OR tul1.u_SuffixName LIKE "%n\\a%", CONCAT_WS("",tul1.u_FirstName, ","), tul1.u_FirstName),
                IF (tul1.u_SuffixName = "NONE" OR tul1.u_SuffixName LIKE "%n/a%" OR tul1.u_SuffixName LIKE "%n\\a%", "",  CONCAT_WS("", tul1.u_SuffixName, ",")),
                IF (tul1.u_MiddleName = "NONE" OR tul1.u_MiddleName LIKE "%n/a%" OR tul1.u_SuffixName LIKE "%n\\a%", "",  tul1.u_MiddleName) 
                        ), "  ", " ") AS student,
        CONCAT_WS(" ",  sc.course_RefNo, "~",  sc.course_Title) AS Course,
        REPLACE(CONCAT_WS(" ",  CONCAT_WS("",tul2.u_LastName, ","),  IF (tul2.u_SuffixName = "NONE" OR tul2.u_SuffixName LIKE "%n/a%" OR tul2.u_SuffixName LIKE "%n\\a%", CONCAT_WS("",tul2.u_FirstName, ","), tul2.u_FirstName),
                IF (tul2.u_SuffixName = "NONE" OR tul2.u_SuffixName LIKE "%n/a%" OR tul2.u_SuffixName LIKE "%n\\a%", "",  CONCAT_WS("", tul2.u_SuffixName, ",")),
                IF (tul2.u_MiddleName = "NONE" OR tul2.u_MiddleName LIKE "%n/a%" OR tul2.u_SuffixName LIKE "%n\\a%", "",  tul2.u_MiddleName) 
                        ), "  ", " ") AS Instructor,
        tfg.fgrade_Grade AS FinalGrade,
        tfl.fl_AY AS AY,
        tfl.fl_SemId AS SemId,
        ss.yrsem_Sem AS Semester,
        tfg.fgrade_DateEncoded,
        tfg.fgrade_Visible,
        tfg.fgrade_Id
    ', false);
    $this->db->from('egmsdbdev.tblfinalgrade AS tfg');
    $this->db->join('egmsdbdev.tblfacultyloading AS tfl', 'tfg.fgrade_FLId = tfl.fl_Id', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('egmsdbdev.tbluserlist AS tul1', 'tul1.u_SpId = tfg.fgrade_SpId', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('egmsdbdev.set_course AS sc', 'tfl.fl_CourseId = sc.course_Id', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('egmsdbdev.tbluserlist AS tul2', 'tfl.fl_FacultyId = tul2.u_Id', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('dbris.set_yrsem AS ss', 'tfl.fl_SemId = ss.yrsem_id', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('egmsdbdev.tblfinalgrade AS tfg2', 'tfg.fgrade_SpId = tfg2.fgrade_SpId AND tfg.fgrade_FLId = tfg2.fgrade_FLId AND tfg.fgrade_Id<tfg2.fgrade_Id', 'left');
    $this->db->where("tfl.fl_CourseId NOT IN ((SELECT nnc_CourseId from set_nonnumericcourse))");
```

Answer (score 0):

Before debugging, I've a couple of questions.

1. Have you tried your MySQL Query in a RDBMS like MySQL sv, phpmyadmin, and so on? if you haven't, please, do it there first to see if it works, then copy/paste on the code.
2. In the [CodeIgniter documentation for Query Builder](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html) states that you need to do `$this->db->select('title, content, date');
   $query = $this->db->get('mytable');` , from what I see on your post, you have tried only the first part without specifying the table that you're trying to use.
3. Please try to give your question a better format, that query can be displayed in a better way, just hit some SHIFT + ENTER on keywords like  REPLACE or you can do it in commas, then with that formatting just select all the text and click on the {} which is to give code format to a text.
4. If you try the approach of MySQL query syntax I recommend the follwing:`$query = "Your query";
   echo $query;` if you do that, you will be able to debbug the query more easily, is even better if you combine it with the 1 item I listed (trying the query on a program like phpmyadmin).  Sometimes my queries won't work because of miss placed '', "", commas,etc and if I use echo, I can see how my query is going to run before performing the actual query.

Comment: Hi!
I will answer all your questions:

1. The actual MySQL runs smoothly and returns valid data as stated in my question.
2. I tried it in detail already... I did not just post my whole attempt here.
3. I will do next time.. I am new here.
4. Already done that but what my situation needs now is the conversion of the query itself.

Thank you for the feedback and clarification.

Comment: Hi again!. Reading a little bit of the groceryCRUD docs, I found out that many of the queries syntax use CodeIgniter ACTIVE RECORD. My point 2 is still valid, you already tried this way. I would advice going to the docs again and search the equivalent of each MySQL command and use something like https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping or https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#method-chaining. This answer may also help https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-62047-post-319010.html. Sadly, that's all I can do for you, wish you good luck!